# Bloc depends on unregistered type - Injectable

Tags: flutter, dart, injectable

I'm using injectable lib according to a tutorial in youtube some of annotations replaced.
but I visit injectable lib in pub.dev look to the changelog and replaced > RegisterAs(Type) by > Injectable(as:Type) but it not working and give unregistered error

```
abstract class IAuthFacade {
  Future<Either<AuthFailure, Unit>> registerWithEmailAndPassword(
      {required EmailAddress emailAddress, required Password password});
  Future<Either<AuthFailure, Unit>> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      {required EmailAddress emailAddress, required Password password});
  Future<Either<AuthFailure, Unit>> signInWithGoogle();
}
```

And here I implemented the Interface

```
@lazySingleton
@Injectable(as: IAuthFacade)
class FirebaseAuthFacade implements IAuthFacade {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth;

  FirebaseAuthFacade(this._auth);

  @override
  Future<Either<AuthFailure, Unit>> registerWithEmailAndPassword({required EmailAddress emailAddress, required Password password}) {
    // TODO: implement registerWithEmailAndPassword
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Future<Either<AuthFailure, Unit>> signInWithEmailAndPassword({required EmailAddress emailAddress, required Password password}) {
    // TODO: implement signInWithEmailAndPassword
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Future<Either<AuthFailure, Unit>> signInWithGoogle() {
    // TODO: implement signInWithGoogle
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

And here is the bloc

```
@injectable
class SignInFormBloc extends Bloc<SignInFormEvent, SignInFormState> {
  final IAuthFacade _authFacade;
}
```

After building it shows me

```
Missing dependencies in sabaclassesorganizer/injection.dart

[SignInFormBloc] depends on unregistered type [IAuthFacade] from package:sabaclassesorganizer/domain/auth/i_auth_facade.dart

Did you forget to annotate the above class(s) or their implementation with @injectable?
or add the right environment keys?
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: any one here to help

Comment: Does `@LazySingleton(as: IAuthFacade)` instead of 
`@lazySingleton
@Injectable(as: IAuthFacade)`
works for you?

Comment: I have the same problem with the said tutorial. ill post an answer if I solve this,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming we followed the same tutorial, you should have a concrete implementation to the `IAuthFacade` called `FirebaseAuthFacade`.

I am using newer package versions than the tutorial, but I can't disclose them. They are close to the latest as of writing this answer.

what worked for me required two steps:

first, replace the annotations on the `FirebaseAuthFacade`:

```dart
@prod
@lazySingleton
@RegisterAs(IAuthFacade)
class FirebaseAuthFacade implements IAuthFacade {
```

with:

```dart
@named
@Injectable(as: AuthFacade)
class FirebaseAuthFacade implements IAuthFacade {
```

second, add a named annotation to the SignInFormBloc constructor:

```dart
SignInFormBloc(@Named('FirebaseAuthFacade') this._authFacade) : super(SignInFormState.initial()) {
```

disclaimer: this may not achieve the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Just Replace **@lazySingleton** and
**@Injectable(as: IAuthFacade)** with **@LazySingleton(as: IAuthFacade)** by following the official documentation https://pub.dev/packages/injectable. You can find this solution under the **Binding abstract classes to implementations** sections.

The complete solution:

```
@LazySingleton(as: IAuthFacade)
class FirebaseAuthFacade implements IAuthFacade {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth;

  FirebaseAuthFacade(this._auth);

  @override
  Future<Either<AuthFailure, Unit>> registerWithEmailAndPassword({required EmailAddress emailAddress, required Password password}) {
    // TODO: implement registerWithEmailAndPassword
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Future<Either<AuthFailure, Unit>> signInWithEmailAndPassword({required EmailAddress emailAddress, required Password password}) {
    // TODO: implement signInWithEmailAndPassword
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Future<Either<AuthFailure, Unit>> signInWithGoogle() {
    // TODO: implement signInWithGoogle
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```